# How to use the checkbox() in MVC2.Please explain with example

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Need to update the check box value to db table when i click the checkbox() without post back in MVC2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541063/need-to-update-the-check-box-value-to-db-table-when-i-click-the-checkbox-withou)

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="SelectedObject" value="cbValue"/>

//How to use check box in Control of MVC
```

Please advice