# Need to update the check box value to db table when i click the checkbox() without post back in MVC2

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-2

```
<input type="checkbox" name="n" value=1 />
<input type="checkbox" name="n" value=2 />
<input type="checkbox" name="n" value=3 />
```

I have above checkbox when i select the this i need to update the DB table without post back.
Please explain.. If possible you can say jquery or ajax method to solve my problem

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking - do you want to know how to handle the POST and bind to a model?

Comment: Thank you for your respond.. Yes Leni

Comment: i want to know how to handle the checkbox value to update the DB without postback

Answer (score 2):

You have to do some sort of request back to the server, whether it's a POST from a form button or an Ajax POST or GET request.

Form button:

```
<form action="/MyApp/HandleClick/" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="SelectedObject" value="cbValue"/>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Or, [Ajax (with jquery):](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

```
 jQuery('input[name=SelectedObject]').click(function() {
     jQuery.ajax({
         url: '/MyApp/HandleClick/',
         data: {
             SelectedObject: this.value,
         }
         success: function() {
             // Process success data...
         }
     });
 });
```

Then your controller:

```
public class MyAppController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult HandleClick(string value)
    {
        // Handle persisting value to database...

        // If posting
        return RedirectToAction("OtherAction");

        // If Ajax
        return Json("Success!");
    }
}
```

That's the simplest example - can't answer more without more details about exactly what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#checkboxid').click(function(){
 $.ajax({ url: 'your_url_for_receiving_data',
type: 'POST',
data: { checkbox: $('#checkboxid').attr('checked') },
success: function(o) { alert('saved'); }
});
```

just create code behind in mvc2 where you will get value from request and save it to db

Answer (score 0):

" />

in controller

public ActionResult(string value)
  {
 return View();

}
it is help you